# Extract specific CSS files to a file with Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

What I'm trying to achieve is a Webpack configuration where CSS is handled by the final JS export, but, some specific files are exported to an external file (to optimize critical CSS loading).

So, the idea is: if the file name start with `_critical-`, put it in a file.

So, here is my `webpack.config.js` for the moment:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/entry.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
        test: /\.s?css$/,
      },
      {
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        }),
        test: /\A_critical-.*\.s?css$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,  
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: { 
            limit: 10000,
            name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
          } 
        }]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ],

  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

And, at some point, I have `import './components/base/_critical-color.scss';` in my code.

When I run Webpack, no error. But no `styles.css` either.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your test regex does not match the filenames

Comment: @Dummy Where do you test it? Because if I try on there https://regex101.com/r/qBmUjq/1 it's matching

Comment: Test with the full path

Comment: @Dummy Oh, I though it was just testing the file name not the fullpath. Make sense then, thanks